# Using Powershell to reverse the sequence numbers in a set of file names

Tags: powershell, file-rename

I am new to using PowerShell (and coding for that matter), all I'm trying to do is rename my files).

I have 222 .jpg's that are named

```
"REF_10001.jpg" 
"REF_10002.jpg" 
"REF_10003.jpg" 
etc
```

but my problem is that they are in the wrong order, I need to reverse them, for example I need

```
"REF_10001.jpg" --> "REF_10222.jpg"
```

and vice versa.

```
"REF_10222.jpg" --> "REF_10001.jpg"
```

Is there a way to do this? I have been struggling for hours to rename my files properly, just to realize they are in the wrong order, I am tempted to just go do them individually at this point.

Also if someone could help me to change the files to read

```
"REF.0001.jpg" 
"REF.0002.jpg" 
etc.
```

that would be great.

Or if what I'm asking isn't possible, I have a back up folder of my image sequence before i started trying to rename them, the files read

```
_0221_Layer 1.jpg
_0220_Layer 2.jpg
...
_0000_Layer 222.jpg
```

I need to change them so that

```
"_0221_Layer 1.jpg"    -->  "Ref.0001.jpg"
...
"_0000_Layer 222.jpg"  -->  "Ref.0222.jpg"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Get-ChildItem ".\Pics\*.jpg" | 
    ForEach-Object {$i = 1} {
            Rename-Item  -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName "$($_.BaseName)-$i.jpg"
            $i++
    }

Get-ChildItem ".\Pics\*.jpg" | 
    ForEach-Object {$j = 222} {
        Rename-Item  -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName "REF_$("1{0:0000}" -f $j).jpg"
        $j--
    }
```

It's seems a bit inefficient to me, in that you need to enumerate twice, but it works on my test files, so will hopefully be good enough to resolve your immediate problem.

The first loop adds a unique 'tag' to the filename that is later discarded - this is needed otherwise you end up with clashes (e.g. if you try to name "REF_10001" to "REF_10222", it will fail since the latter already exists.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I just have a question (sorry if its really stupid), can I just copy and paste that in there or do I need to change anything? I tried and got an error that starts like this " Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\Luischen\Documents\Chantelle Badenhorst\Y2.C2.A4_Force and Weight
(03-2018)\08. Maya\sourceimages\TEST\New folder\Pics' because it does not exist. ...." sorry again, I only found out about powershell today so I don't really know what i'm doing

Comment: Replace the _".\Pics\\*.jpg"_ path with the exact one to your pictures folder.  For example: _"C:\Users\Chantelle\Desktop\Pictures\\*.jpg_.  Change it in both places in my example.

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked for me, except it didn't change the first 9 files for some reason, but they are easy to change individually, this happened with the other 2 answers below that I tried, but your method was the easiest for me to understand. Thank you again this saved me a lot of time and effort.

Comment: I finally realize why it looks like the first 9 don't change, I didn't notice but my jpgs are layers i exported from photoshop and for some reason it made a duplicate of the first 9 and added them at the end so they do change I just didn't realize that there was a duplicate so it seemed to not change.

Answer (score 1):

The following works with a variable number of files and also performs the desired name transformation (in addition to reversing the sequence numbers):

```
# Enumerate the files in reverse alphabetical order - which thanks to the 0-padding
# is equivalent to the reverse sequence-number order - and rename them with 
# an ascending 0-padded sequence number.
# Note that in-place renaming is only possible because the new filename pattern
# - REF.*.jpg - doesn't conflict with the old one, REF_1*.jpg
$iref = [ref] 0  # sequence-number helper variable
Get-ChildItem -Filter REF_1*.jpg | Sort-Object Name -Descending |
  Rename-Item -NewName { 'REF.{0:0000}.jpg' -f (++$iref.Value) } -WhatIf
```

Note: The use of `-WhatIf` *previews* the command without actually running it.
If the preview shows the intended operations, remove `-WhatIf` to actually perform it.

Note the need to use a `[ref]`-typed aux. variable for the sequence number and to increment it via its `.Value` property in the script block (`{ ... }`) that calculates the new name, because the script block runs in a different variable scope and therefore cannot directly modify variables in the caller's scope.

Comment: Thank you for your effort to answer my question, your method was also a little more complicated for me to understand but I tried it and it worked, (it did give me a small error but it worked regardless), except for the first 9 files as well, but its not a problem to individually change those.

Comment: @ChantelleBadenhorst: I later realized that my solution was needlessly complicated, so I've simplified it substantially - hopefully it is easier to understand now. I wonder what's different about the first 9 files.

Comment: It is a lot easier to understand now, thank you. I'm really not sure, they don't look different from the rest so i don't know why the don't respond the same, but its really not a train smash its just 9 and not all of them :)

Comment: I finally realize why it looks like the first 9 don't change, I didn't notice but my jpgs are layers i exported from photoshop and for some reason it made a duplicate of the first 9 and added them at the end so they do change I just didn't realize that there was a duplicate so it seemed to not change.

Answer (score 1):

My assumptions:

- We do not know in advance if the numbers in the file names always follow each other
- We do not know in advance the number of digits in these numbers
- I would only take files starting REF_ followed by numbers and ending with the extension jpg

So I propose a solution that reverses the first name with the last one, the second with the last before and so on :

```
$DirWithFiles="C:\Temp\DirWithFilesToRename"

#Creation to new dir for copy
$Temporatydir=  [System.IO.Path]::Combine([System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath(), [System.IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName())
New-Item -ItemType Directory $Temporatydir

#get all file jgp with format REF_ + Number + .jpg and order by number
$ListFile=Get-ChildItem $DirWithFiles -File -Filter "REF_*.jpg" | where BaseName -Match "^REF_\d{1,}$" | select Fullname, Name, @{N="Number";E={[int]($_.BaseName -split '_')[1]}} | sort Number

#copy files into new temporary dir and rename 1 position by N position, 2 by N-1, 3 by N - 2 etc...
for ($i = 0; $i -lt ($ListFile.Count / 2 ); $i++)
{ 
    Copy-Item $ListFile[$i].FullName "$Temporatydir\$($ListFile[$ListFile.Count-$i - 1].Name)" -Force
    Copy-Item $ListFile[$ListFile.Count-$i - 1].FullName "$Temporatydir\$($ListFile[$i].Name)" -Force
}

#Copy all files in temporary dir to initial dir with overwriting
Get-ChildItem $Temporatydir | Copy-Item -Destination $DirWithFiles


#delete temporary dir
Remove-Item $Temporatydir -Recurse
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort to answer my question, your method was a little more complicated for me to understand but I tried it and it worked, except for the first 9 files as well, but its not a problem to individually change those.

Comment: You 9 first files have different format name? Not REF_NNNN.jpg? If my code is ok, you can click on up if you have right

Comment: I copy and pasted the file name from one of the first 9 and then the 10th one for you to see, I dont know if its just me being dyslexic but I think they are the same format, "REF_10001.jpg"  "REF_10010.jpg"

Comment: I finally realize why it looks like the first 9 don't change, I didn't notice but my jpgs are layers i exported from photoshop and for some reason it made a duplicate of the first 9 and added them at the end so they do change I just didn't realize that there was a duplicate so it seemed to not change.

Answer (score 1):

A simple method to reverse the order is:

- subtract the highest number+1 from each file number.
- to remove the resulting negative sign multiply with -1 or use the `[math]::abs()` function.
- To get the number from the (Base)Name a Regular Expression `'^REF_1(\d+)?'` captures () the number without the leading 1.
- a format string operator `"REF.{0:0000}.jpg" -f` is used to create the name inserting the calculated new number with 4 places
- As the prefix changes there is danger overwriting a file from the other end.

---

```
Get-ChildItem REF_1*.jpg | 
  Where-Object BaseName -match '^REF_1(\d+)?' |
    Rename-Item -NewName {"REF.{0:0000}.jpg" -f (-1 *($Matches[1]-223))} -whatif
```

If the output looks OK remove the trailing `-WhatIf` parameter.

Sample output last line:

> What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: REF_10222.jpg
>   Destination: REF.0001.jpg".

Comment: Thank you for your response, I tried this now and it also worked.