# How to batch rename files including a number and the modified date?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-rename

Edit: I should have gone for Date Taken instead, as Date Modified is sometimes off by one hour for the pictures we're working with.

I am trying to write something that will rename files to the following format:

```
24024 25-12-2014 20.18.JPG
24025 26-12-2014 18.01.JPG
24026 26-12-2014 18.01.JPG
24027 30-12-2014 17.05.JPG
24028 31-12-2014 15.09.JPG
24029 31-12-2014 15.19.JPG
```

I need this for organising my mother's pictures in the way my father designed. I looked specifically for ways to do it with a cmd batch file first, but it seemed too complicated. I am now trying to use the PowerShell.

I have tried this, which works:

`Get-ChildItem *.JPG | Rename-Item -newname {$_.LastWriteTime.toString("dd-MM-yyyy HH.mm") + ".JPG"}`

But I haven't managed to include a variable counting with that. This does not compile:

`$a = 10; Get-ChildItem *.JPG | {Rename-Item -newname {$_.LastWriteTime.toString("dd-MM-yyyy HH.mm") + ".JPG"}; $a++}`

Nor does this, which I found in another question.

`Foreach ($Item in Get-ChildItem *.JPG) {Rename-Item -newname {$_.LastWriteTime.toString("dd-MM-yyyy HH.mm") + ".JPG"}}`

Comment: What is your plan if more than one file has the same LastWriteTime? Do you have the "counting" in order to add to the new filename? If not, what is the "counting" used for?

Comment: @lit: You can see in the format example. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$Path = 'D:\'  # the folder where the jpg files are
$Count = 10    # the starting number. gets increased for each file
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter '*.JPG' -File | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Rename-Item -NewName ('{0:00000} {1}.JPG' -f $Count++, ($_.LastWriteTime.toString("dd-MM-yyyy HH.mm")))
}
```

---

**EDIT 1**

---

To name them in chronological order, just add a `Sort-Object` to the script, like this:

```
$Path = 'D:\'  # the folder where the jpg files are
$Count = 10    # the starting number. gets increased for each file
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter '*.JPG' -File | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Rename-Item -NewName ('{0:00000} {1}.JPG' -f $Count++, ($_.LastWriteTime.toString("dd-MM-yyyy HH.mm")))
}
```

---

**EDIT 2**

---

As per your last comment, to get the date from the Exif data in the image, you need a function to get the `DateTimeOriginal` from the file if possible.

You can do that with the code below:

```
function Get-ExifDate {
    # returns the 'DateTimeOriginal' property from the Exif metadata in an image file if possible
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'ByName')]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true, Position = 0, ParameterSetName = 'ByName')]
        [Alias('FullName', 'FileName')]
        [ValidateScript({ Test-Path -Path $_ -PathType Leaf})]
        [string]$Path,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, Position = 0, ParameterSetName = 'ByObject')]
        [System.IO.FileInfo]$FileObject
    )

    Begin {
        Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Drawing'
    }
    Process {
        # the function received a path, not a file object
        if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'ByName') {
            $FileObject = Get-Item -Path $Path -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        }
        # Parameters for FileStream: Open/Read/SequentialScan
        $streamArgs = @(
            $FileObject.FullName
            [System.IO.FileMode]::Open
            [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read
            [System.IO.FileShare]::Read
            1024,     # Buffer size
            [System.IO.FileOptions]::SequentialScan
        )
        try {
            $stream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream -ArgumentList $streamArgs
            $metaData = [System.Drawing.Imaging.Metafile]::FromStream($stream)

            # get the 'DateTimeOriginal' property (ID = 36867) from the metadata
            # Tag Dec  TagId Hex  TagName           Writable  Group    Notes
            # -------  ---------  -------           --------  -----    -----
            # 36867    0x9003     DateTimeOriginal  string    ExifIFD  (date/time when original image was taken)
            # see: https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/EXIF.html

            # get the date taken as an array of bytes
            $exifDateBytes = $metaData.GetPropertyItem(36867).Value
            # transform to string, but beware that this string is Null terminated, so cut off the trailing 0 character
            $exifDateString = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($exifDateBytes).TrimEnd("`0")
            # return the parsed date
            return [datetime]::ParseExact($exifDateString, "yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss", $null) 
        }
        catch{
            Write-Warning -Message "Could not read Exif data from '$($FileObject.FullName)'"
        }
        finally {
            If ($metaData) {$metaData.Dispose()}
            If ($stream)   {$stream.Close()}
        }
    }
}
```

Using that function, your code would look then like this:

```
$Path = 'D:\'  # the folder where the jpg files are
$Count = 10    # the starting number. gets increased for each file

# start a loop to gather the files and reset their LastWriteTime property to the one read from the Exif data.
# pipe the result to the Sort-Object cmdlet and enter another ForEach-Object loop to perform the rename.
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter '*.JPG' -File | ForEach-Object {
    $date = $_ | Get-ExifDate
    if ($date) { 
        $_.LastWriteTime = $date
    }
    $_
} | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | ForEach-Object {
    $newName = '{0:00000} {1}.JPG' -f $Count++, ($_.LastWriteTime.toString("dd-MM-yyyy HH.mm"))
    # output some info to the console
    Write-Host "Renaming file '$($_.Name)' to '$newName'"
    $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $newName
}
```

---

This uses string formatting `-f`. You give it a template string with numbered placeholders between curly braces.

The first one `{0:00000}` is a way of formatting a number with preceeding zero characters up to a length of 5 characters in this case.

The second one `{1}` gets replaced by the formatted date string.

The `$Count` variable gets increased on each iteration using the `++` syntax.

Comment: Simple and effective, but you should really explain what you're doing better. Not everybody is familiar with string formatting, or the `++` method.

Comment: Thank you! There's a problem though: they're not all in the right order. Here's an example: https://i.imgur.com/eFmxAhS.png Do you know how I can make sure it names them from oldest to newest?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician You're right. I have added some explanation to it now.

Comment: @607 I have added a `Sort-Object` to it, so the files will be numbered oldest to newest.

Comment: Hello, your script has been very helpful, but I just realised that on some sets of pictures the Date Modified is off by one hour from when the picture was taken. I discovered the Date Taken metadata, which I should use instead. I have looked into ways to get this property, but I'm afraid I'm not yet experienced enough with Powershell commands to figure out how to implement this into your script. Could you help me?

Comment: @607 Ok, I have edited the code again and put a function to read the date taken from the Exif metadata of the image. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks @Theo, there's quite a bit more to that than I thought! Isn't there a way to sort by that as well, though? I have tried to put the function after the Sort-Object and I have tried to make a variable for the result of the Sort-Object, but in the first case it didn't seem to sort at all, and in the second case it said ```Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Theo's good answer (+1) without using a ForEach-Object
as `Rename-Item` accepts piped input directly.

This requires a script block for the `-NewName` parameter and in turn the `$count` needs to be a `[ref]`
(see this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51006527/6811411) from mklement0)

The [-format operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html) allows to apply format strings in the placeholders directly

```
$Path = 'D:\'      # the folder where the jpg files are
$Count = [ref] 10  # the starting number. gets increased for each file

Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter '*.JPG' -File | Sort-Object LastWriteTime |
    Rename-Item -NewName {"{0:D5} {1:dd-MM-yyyy HH.mm}{2}" -f  `
                          $Count.Value++,$_.LastWriteTime,$_.Extension} -whatif
```

If the output looks OK, remove the trailing `-WhatIf` parameter